# apt-get install package from third-party repository

Tags: debian

How do you install a specific package using `apt-get` from a third-party repository?

I added the NodeSource Node.js repo to my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x buster main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x buster main
```

I updated apt and can see the package using `apt-cache policy nodejs`:

```
nodejs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.9.3~dfsg-12
  Version table:
     9.11.1-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x buster/main amd64 Packages
     8.11.1~dfsg-2 500
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.3~dfsg-12 990
        990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
```

How do I instruct to `apt-get` that I want to install the package from *nodesource*?

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -t nodesource nodejs
sudo apt-get install -t node_9.x nodejs
sudo apt-get install -t buster/main nodejs
sudo apt-get install -t deb.nodesource.com nodejs
sudo apt-get install -t deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x
```

But all of those fail with the same error (for the corresponding release):

```
E: The value 'deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Comment: `apt-get install package=version`.  In your case, you would need to do `apt-get install nodejs=9.11.1-1nodesource1`.  Alternatively use apt policy files and set hte node repo to a higher priority for the nodejs packages

Comment: @ivanivan Will the lock me into that version? Or is that just a clarifier?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I used it I needed a very specific version to run something someone else provided that I couldn't change/update so upgrades/updates weren't a concern

Comment: @ivanivan I'd prefer for it to be updateable through an `apt-get upgrade`, but if that's the only solution I guess I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the version from nodesource is newer, so just `apt install nodejs` should give you what you want.

You can also specify that you want a particular version with `apt install nodejs=<version>`. This only affects what will be installed by that partcular command, it is not remembered, so the next time you run `apt update; apt upgrade`, it will try to upgrade the package the usual way (which is probably what you want).

You could also read about apt pinning and give that repository a higher priority, then you can make apt prefer packages from there for all future. The risk is if that they suddenly but something up unrelated to nodejs, you'll also get that, you could try to avoid that by only pinning nodejs, but then you'll have trouble if they split the package some day. But no solution can predict your future wishes and comply with them.

Comment: Re your first paragraph, look at the priorities which are already present — they’re the reason why plain `apt install` isn’t working.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen that testing had that high a priority, you're right something will have to be done to install that version, but luckily (considering OP's comments) testing's priority isn't so high that it will downgrade (as far as I remember priorities) to get to that, so when installed it should be easy to keep upgraded.

Comment: I agree, the rest of your answer’s fine (hence my earlier +1).

Comment: I knew the technical reason the *nodesource* nodejs wasn't getting chosen was because of the priority. In my case, I want to keep the *testing* repo the highest in general. @ivanivan had mentioned in the comments that I could install a specific version; however, I didn't know if it would pin or lock that version and not upgrade unless I pinned a newer version. Thanks for the clarification that that only indicates which package to install but does not pin that specific version.